# Define class inside class - like java

Tags: dart

In **Dart** it seems not possible to define classes inside other classes (like in java).
What is the best way to define static nested consts? like

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass.VALUE1;
```

**Java**

```
class OuterClass {
    ...
    static class StaticNestedClass {
        public final static String VALUE1 = "wip12";
        ...
    }
    class InnerClass {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Track https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/3755